# SQL Server employee manager hierarchy remove circular reference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an employee list; each employee is assigned to a manager. The manager will change at any time for the employees. I am using a recursive CTE to get the manager's employee.

I am getting this error

> The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

when hierarchy is like this:

```
x  => y
y  => z
z  => x
x  => y
```

I want to skip the circular reference for employee x => y when getting manager hierarchy employees.

Comment: I think you have an unusual management structure if I can be my manager's manager.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The manager mapping contains both the current employee list and the manager change history table. we are taking backup when the manager changed for an employee.  To get hierarchy I use both the employee table and log table. so in that case the manager hierarchy will be like this

Comment: Track hierachy path, stop when adding a pair existing in the path

Comment: Why aren't you using SQL Server's `hierarchyid` type in order to prevent this thing from happening in the first place?

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: @TheImpaler I want to skip this hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

You example data is a bit vague (maybe too simplified). Nevertheless, you can walk the graph and detect cycles using a recursive CTE.

For example, you can create the example data as:

```
create table t (
  k int,
  emp_id char(1),
  manager_id char(1)
);

insert into t (k, emp_id, manager_id) values
  (1, 'x', 'y'),
  (2, 'y', 'z'),
  (3, 'z', 'x'),
  (4, 'x', 'y');
```

Then the query that starts walking from the first row and detects cycles can take the form (see running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8a7322a06e8f2f7d842047674c4cbc3)):

```
with
n as (
  select k, emp_id, manager_id, 0 as level,
    cast(concat(':', emp_id, ':') as varchar(1000)) as path, 0 as cycle_found
  from t where k = 1
 union all
  select t.k, t.emp_id, t.manager_id, n.level + 1,
    cast(concat(path, t.emp_id, ':') as varchar(1000)),
    sign(charindex(concat(':', t.emp_id, ':'), path))
  from n
  join t on t.emp_id = n.manager_id
    and n.cycle_found = 0
)
select * from n;
```

Result:

```
k  emp_id  manager_id  level  path       cycle_found 
-- ------- ----------- ------ ---------- ----------- 
1  x       y           0      :x:        0           
2  y       z           1      :x:y:      0           
3  z       x           2      :x:y:z:    0           
1  x       y           3      :x:y:z:x:  1           
4  x       y           3      :x:y:z:x:  1
```

Notice the cycle is detected by storing all the walked nodes in the column `path`. Also notice that once a cycle is detected the query stops walking that path immediately by using the condition `and n.cycle_found = 0`.